# Form submits with a varied success PHP+IFRAME+AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, form-submit

I have a 3 steps checkout.

1. STEP: User upload a photo and crop it.
2. STEP: User add his shipping information.
3. STEP: User pay with PayPal.

Now, i want to save an information about the order in two steps.

I save the image information + upload image using iframe:

```
 <form id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/upload.php" onsubmit="return checkForm()" target="image_upload_frame">

 <iframe name="image_upload_frame" height="1" width="1" style="visibility: hidden"></iframe>
```

My upload.php upload the image to `/cache/` directory and put data into database about link, framesize, and price, then it echo `row_id` of the last row.

But it works sometimes and sometimes not! I mean I some time it do save information in DB and in some times no.

Any suggestions?

Here is another peace of code, where i call to `.submit()` function

```
$(".steps a").click(function(){
                    $(".steps a").removeClass("selected");
                    $(this).addClass("selected");
                });
                $("#st1,#0stepnext").click(function(){
                    $('#upload_form').submit(function(){
                        $("#pagestep1").show();
                        $(".scrolldown").show();
                        $("#pagestep2").hide();
                        $("#pagestep3").hide();
                    });

                });
                $("#st2, #1stepnext").click(function(){
                    $("#pagestep2").show();
                    $("#pagestep1").hide();
                    $("#pagestep3").hide();
                    $(".scrolldown").hide();
                });
                $("#st3, #2stepnext").click(function(){
                    $("#pagestep3").show();
                    $("#pagestep1").hide();
                    $("#pagestep2").hide();
                    $(".scrolldown").hide();
                });
```

Here is a part of my php:

```
$sImage = uploadImageFile();
global $wpdb;

$price = (int)$_POST['price'];
$frame = $_POST['filedim'];
$link = $sImage;
$id = $wpdb->insert_id;

$wpdb->insert('orders',
    array(
        'price'=>$price,
        'frame'=>$frame,
        'link'=>$link

    ),
    array(
        '%d',
        '%s',
        '%s'

    )
);
echo $wpdb->insert_id;
```

Comment: Are you putting the information in the database before or after the file is uploaded? The problem sounds like you don't know at what point something is going wrong. I suspect that the jquery code is working fine, but the PHP code that puts the data in the database has a problem. Show us your insert query from PHP. You might not be escaping your data, or maybe large uploads are killing the connection. I suggest separating the upload process from the database insertion process.

Comment: @degenerate I just added the php code to the main question.

Comment: If there is an error in your `uploadImageFile()` function, the order will never be inserted. Since there are so many things that could be going wrong, you need to insert your order information FIRST, and then do the image upload. After successful image upload, `UPDATE` the order in the database with the image link. This will help you determine at what point your application is failing.